# Stop jquery function after x seconds

Tags: jquery, function, refresh, webcam

I'm running this script on my website to show an image from my webcam. The image refreshes after 5 seconds, but I want this function to stop after 30 seconds, so I don't waste too much bandwidth. How can I do this ?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>jQuery Reload iframe for every 5 seconds</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
setInterval(refreshiframe, 5000);
});
function refreshiframe() {
$('#testframe').attr('src', $('#testframe').attr('src'));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<iframe id="testframe" src="http://50.21.204.200/snapshot.jpg" width="640px" height="480px"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) is like `setInterval` except it invokes its callback only once.

Use `setTimeout` to enqueue a callback for 30 seconds in the future, which stops the first interval with [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval):

```
var intervalID = setInterval(refreshiframe, 5000);

setTimeout(function () { clearInterval(intervalID); }, 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep track of the elapsed time since you started and not start the next timeout if you've exceeded the time.

```
$(function() {
   var start = new Date().getTime();

   function run() {
       refreshiframe();
       // if we haven't exceeded 30 seconds, schedule the next refresh
       if ((new Date()).getTime() - start < (30 * 1000)) {
           setTimeout(run, 5000);
       }
   }
   // do the first one
   setTimeout(run, 5000);

   function refreshiframe() {
       $('#testframe').attr('src', $('#testframe').attr('src'));
   }
});
```

---

Or, you could just keep a counter and only refresh a certain number of times and then cancel the interval after that number of times:

```
$(function() {
   var cntr = 0;

   var interval = setInterval(function() {
       refreshiframe();
       // if we've already done the max number of refreshes, 
       //    then cancel the interval
       if (++cntr > 6) {
           clearInterval(interval);
       }
   }, 5000);

   function refreshiframe() {
       $('#testframe').attr('src', $('#testframe').attr('src'));
   }
});
```